# Search function error when retrieving data from table

Tags: cobol, mainframe

```
    01 emp-rec.
       05 emp-rec-num               pic x(3).

    01 ws-table-data.
       05 filler                   pic x(12)
           value 'A12FIRST ONT'.
       05 filler                   pic x(12)
           value 'A14FIRST QUE'.
       05 filler                   pic x(12)
           value 'B10THIRD QUE'.
       05 filler                   pic x(12)
           value 'B12SECONDONT'.
       05 filler                   pic x(12)
           value 'B14SECONDONT'.
       05 filler                   pic x(12)
           value 'C09THIRD ONT'.
       05 filler                   pic x(12)
           value 'C11FIRST QUE'.
       05 filler                   pic x(12)
           value 'C13FIRST ONT'.
       05 filler                   pic x(12)
           value 'C21FIRST ONT'.
       05 filler                   pic x(12)
           value 'C22FIRST ONT'.
       05 filler                   pic x(12)
           value 'C23SECONDQUE'.
       05 filler                   pic x(12)
           value 'C25FIRST QUE'.
       05 filler                   pic x(12)
           value 'C27SECONDQUE'.

01 ws-table REDEFINES ws-table-data.
       05 ws-table-element OCCURS 13 times 
       INDEXED BY data-index.
           10 ws-operator-number   pic x(3).
           10 ws-operator-type     pic x(6).
           10 ws-operator-province pic x(3).

50-process-table-records.
       set data-index to 1.
       search ws-table-element
           when (ws-operator-number(data-index) = emp-rec-num)
               move ws-operator-type(data-index) to detail-line-type
               move ws-operator-province(data-index) 
                   to detail-line-province
           when (ws-operator-number(data-index) is not equal to 
               emp-rec-num)
                   move 'Operator Not Found' to detail-line-type
       end-search.
```

Output: https://prnt.sc/l5h64p

I have no idea why the first record in the table is printing 13 times, but it is supposed to iterate through the table.  When emp-rec from the input file matches ws-operator-number, ws-operator-type and ws-operator-province are both supposed to be moved to the print line and printed, if not a messaged is displayed on the line instead.

Any and all help is appretiated, thanks!

Comment: Nothing to do with JCL - please drop that tag.

Answer (score 3):

Your second `when` phrase is the negation of the first. Each `when` phrase should be used to determine when the `search` statement should terminate. In effect you are telling the search to end if `em-rec-no` does not match the first entry of the table.

Change the code to match this.

```
50-process-table-records.
       set data-index to 1.
       search ws-table-element
           at end
               move 'Operator Not Found' to detail-line-type
           when (ws-operator-number(data-index) = emp-rec-num)
               move ws-operator-type(data-index) to detail-line-type
               move ws-operator-province(data-index) 
                   to detail-line-province
       end-search.
```

Without knowing how `50-process-table-records` is used, I can't tell if that will fix the problem of printing the same data 13 times.